# How to modify TList<record> value?

Tags: delphi, generics

Delphi 2010
How to modify TList < record > value ?

```
type TTest = record a,b,c:Integer end;
var List:TList<TTest>;
    A:TTest;
    P:Pointer;
....
....

List[10] := A;  <- OK
List[10].a:=1;  <- Here compiler error : Left side cannot be assined to
P:=@List[10];   <- Error: Variable requied
```

Comment: ridiculous error. and no one cares to teach it. its a shame how they do the docs.

Answer (score 11):

```
A := List[10];
A.a := 1;
list[10] := A;
```

You don't have to do this with objects because they're reference types, (accessed through a pointer which the compiler manages internally to keep it out of your hair,) but records are value types so it doesn't work that way.

Comment: it's a simple and strong way. but when the size of the record is very huge the stack overflows because of the local variable A and if this works in a loop or loops it's very slow.

Answer (score 10):

You've hit upon a snag with using records.

Consider this code:

```
function Test: TTest;
begin
    ...
end;

Test.a := 1;
```

What your code looks like to the compiler is actually this:

```
TTest temp := Test;
temp.a := 1;
```

The compiler is telling you, with the error message, that the assignment is pointless, since it will only assign a new value to a temporary record value, which will be instantly forgotten.

Also, the `@List[10]` is invalid because `List[10]` again returns only a temporary record value, so taking the address of that record is rather pointless.

However, reading and writing the whole record is OK.

So to summarize:

```
List[10] := A;  <- writing a whole record is OK
List[10].a:=1;  <- List[10] returns a temporary record, pointless assignment
P:=@List[10];   <- List[10] returns a temporary record, its address is pointless
```

Comment: However the property items is read-write, and i think delphi could understand that Items[1].a:=123 meens Items[1]:=TType(123,oldval2,oldval3)

Comment: But it doesn't... The important part is not what the compiler *could* do, but what it *actually does*.

Comment: @Astronavigator: Yes, the property is R/W, but you are not accessing the field directly. It just return a copy of the field. Check Mason's answer to work around this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store records, dynamic arrays are more suited to handling them :

```
type TTest = record a,b,c : Integer end;
type TTestList = array of TTest;
var List:TTestList;
    A:TTest;
    P:Pointer;
....
....

SetLength( List, 20 );
List[10]   := A; //<- OK
List[10].a := 1; //<- Ok
P := @List[10];  //<- Not advised (the next SetLength(List,xx) will blow the address away),
                 //   but technically works
```

If you need to add methods to manipulate these data, you can store this array as the field of a class, and add your methods to this class.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manipulate objects in that form, it is better to use TObjectList instead of TList, and define the structure as a class rather than a record:

```
type TTest = class a,b,c:Integer end;
var List:TObjectList<TTest>;
    A:TTest; // A is an object so there's no need for a pointer
....
....
List.Add(TTest.Create);
List.Last.a := 1;
A:=List.Last;
```